Simple Postgres View Resulting in Poor Query Planning
In postgres (16.2) I have a very simple table:
CREATE TABLE messages(
    id                  UUID             PRIMARY KEY,
    commitment          bytea            NOT NULL,
    message             bytea            NOT NULL,
    index               bigint           NOT NULL,
    sub_index           int              NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    context             bytea            NOT NULL,
    vx_signature        bytea            NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX messages_commitment_idx ON messages(commitment, id);
CREATE INDEX messages_commitment_index_idx ON messages(commitment, index);

Note, the primary key on messages.id.
Querying this table works exactly as expected:
SELECT
      encode(commitment, 'hex') as commitment_hex,
      encode(message, 'hex') as message_hex,
      encode(vx_signature, 'hex') as vx_signature_hex,
      uuid_v7_to_timestamptz(id) as created,
      *
    FROM messages
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 100
    ;

It will use the primary key, exactly as you'd expect
Expected Results
But creating a simple view, to make the query cleaner:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW messages_view AS (
    SELECT
      encode(commitment, 'hex') as commitment_hex,
      encode(message, 'hex') as message_hex,
      encode(vx_signature, 'hex') as vx_signature_hex,
      uuid_v7_to_timestamptz(id) as created,
      *
    FROM messages
  );

And querying the view:
SELECT * FROM messages_view ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100;

Results in a very poor query plan and doesn't use the primary key any more (?!?!):
https://gist.github.com/husseinhere/2a99a44ddcc377ac81329b3af9c0cecf
Is this expected behavior?

Please provide the faulty query plan as part of the question's text, not a screenshot.

(you can run EXPLAIN ANALYZE at a psql command line if the UI you're using doesn't allow output in copy/paste-friendly form).

Please use explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) to get all the details. In plain text

@FrankHeikens done, hope that helps

That's a strange one! What happens when you lower the setting for random_page_cost to favor an index scan? Because it looks like that you run on a default configuration, that is just a functional configuration and not a performance optimized one. However, the query plan is just weird and I have no explanation for it.

Can you reproduce this without the use of the (unknown to rme) uuid_v7_to_timestamptz function?
